# I want to send email from my gmail account using php i am searching for answer on net since 4 hours but error appears

Tags: php

I am using wamp server and I have following code in my `final.php`. I am also 
adding error that appears as below after code as comment kindly check that as.

I am newer to php. I am finding simple code so that I can sent message through my account, but I don't understand why this code do not have option for password.

Is password require? Please help me on this with detail and I also need to send email to multiple users simultaneously.

```
<?php
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP

    $mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server



    $mail->From     = "63yogesh@gmail.com";

    $mail->AddAddress("11ce028@charusat.edu.in");


    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";

    $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;



    if(!$mail->Send()) {

    echo 'Message was not sent.';

    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

    } else {

    echo 'Message has been sent.';

    }

    ?>


    //The following From address failed: 63yogesh@gmail.com Message was not sent.Mailer error: The following From address failed: 63yogesh@gmail.com
```

SMTP server error: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. jw8sm18271654pbc.73 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0):

The [example](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps) here says you have to set several data, such as authentication:

```
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "yourname@example.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
```

and SMTP port number:

```
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;
```

EDIT:
This is the [Basic Example using SMTP](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp) from their official site, try to edit it with your infos

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php'); //include("class.smtp.php"); //optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$body = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                            // 1 = errors and messages
                                            // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: is there anything other change require @Phate01

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp3\www\Project\phpmail\final.php on line 12                                                           i have written 12.       $mail->Password="********";